# Android - How I can put different Image resources to the SimpleAdapter?

Tags: java, android, simpleadapter

I'm creating a SimpleAdapter with this code

---

```
String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_CHECKED,   ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE };
int[] to = { R.id.tvText, R.id.cbChecked, R.id.ivImg };
SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item,from, to);
lvSimple = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSimple);  
lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);`
```

---

But I need an individual icon for each item

```
if(checkData()) return R.drawable.img0;
else return R.drawable.img1;
```

How I can do that trick without writing custom adapter?

Comment: If you want individual icon then you have to use custom adapter.

Comment: How I can create it? Is there any ready-to-use code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need put different Image resources to the SimpleAdapter. you Just put different size in android different folder(mdpi, hdpi) with same name. Android automatically take correct according to android device size.

Thanks

Comment: I'm writing a filebrowser, and I need to set a file icon or a folder icon. The problem isn't in image sizes.